# Click parent of element that its attribute contains string

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to press the `a` tag that has an `img` child that the src of the `img` contains: `24.png`

There is only one element.

I tried something like:

```
List<IWebElement> elements;

elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//img[contains(@src,'24.png')]/..")).ToList();
elements[0].Click();
```

But elements catch 0 elements.

This is the html content:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="location.href='Details.php?ID=1'">
    <img src="/new/24.png">
</a>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: so the `src` attribute contains `jump_ad.png` instead of `24.png`?

Comment: sorry, I updated the topic..

Comment: your XPath as well as this one : `//a[img[contains(@src,'24.png')]]` able to return the `<a>` tag in XPath tester given sample markup you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your img src attribute is "/new/jump_ad.png"
It doesn't contain the string '24.png'.
That's why you don't get any elements when looking  for '24.png'

and try first without the '/..' at the end